# Is a function generating styled-components keyframes expensive?

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

while working with styled-components i was trying to create a function with some inputs returning a css tagged function which needed some specific keyframes (tightly coupled with my css tag function).

I ended up defining my keyframes inside the function to have access to the closure and was asking my self if the fact to redefine each time my keyframes for each call of the function could be expensive in terms of performance, and if there was a better way to handle this case.

Here is a snippet which illustrate what I try to explain, of course my question make only sense for a much bigger and complex keyframe than this one :

```
const growBorder = (color, from, to) => {

  const grow = keyframes`
    from { border: ${from} solid ${color}; }
    to { border: ${to} solid ${color}; }
  `

  return css`
    border: ${from} solid ${color};
    animate: ${grow} 3s linear 1s infinite alternate;
`
}



const Button = styled.button`
  ${growBorder('purple', '1px', '3px')}
`


const UglyButton = styled.button`
  ${growBorder('red', '10px', '30px')}
`

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. Creating `keyframes` like yours is expensive.

If you look at the [definition of `keyframes`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/b9e8a1f4631b4eb20940b5123ca7736ac3e7322e/src/constructors/keyframes.js#L24) inside `styled-components`, you can see that every time `styled-components` sees a `keyframes` helper, it hashes the content of the `keyframes` declaration. If no match is found (as would be the case for dynamic `keyframes` like yours), it will inject a new style rule into the document's style sheet, forcing a global reflow.